# Playing a muted video without interrupting background music

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

My design calls for a video playing in the background of my login screen, exactly like 6snap has.

I would like to avoid the default behavior of stopping the user's music when the video starts to play. My video does not have sound.

I'm using:

```
<MediaElement Source="MyVideo.mp4" />
```

I tried setting `IsMuted=true` which didn't help. Does anyone have an idea how 6snap managed it?

Edit: currently trying the animated gif route. Using the ImageTools 3rd party library and having converted my MP4, it works fine. My 9 second 640x1136 3MB video became a 41MB GIF, so I have to reduce the quality drastically. Still trying to find a better way if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do that with *Background Audio* and *MediaElement*, hence [as MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202883%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Detaileddescription):

> When a MediaElement control plays audio or video content, any background sounds or media already playing are halted. The app launches the playback experience when the user taps the control. Only one MediaElement control can operate at a time.

It's no matter you have no sound - when you start to play all background sounds/media are halted.

I'm not sure how the App you have mentioned achieved that, but maybe you can try with DirectX/XNA - thought I've not tried this and don't know if that would help.